# SQl Server CTE RECURSIVE how to improve performance for large data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a bad performance in my CTE Recursive script. it took 1:23 minutes to execute with 12925 records. can I add some paging, or anything to improve the performance. here's my code

```
WITH cte(GenealogyID,GenealogySponsorId,GenealogyTypeId,CustomerId,Level) AS
(   
    SELECT
        e.Id AS GenealogyID, 
        e.GenealogySponsorId,
        e.GenealogyTypeId, 
        e.CustomerId,
        0 AS Level 
    FROM Genealogy AS e
    WHERE e.CustomerId = 53591  AND e.GenealogyTypeId = 50

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        child.Id AS GenealogyID,  
        child.GenealogySponsorId, 
        child.GenealogyTypeId, 
        child.CustomerId,
        Level+1 
    FROM Genealogy child 
    JOIN cte parent on parent.GenealogyID = child.GenealogySponsorId
    where child.GenealogyTypeId > 0 AND child.CustomerID <> 53591
)
select count(*) from cte
```

Comment: May this blog helpful to you... `http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/`

Comment: Look at the execution plan.

Comment: Have you got any indexes on your Genealogy table?

Comment: yep, Primary Key as index